# Why random input is recommended for Stochastic Gradiant Descent

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

Correct me if i am wrong?

1) For Batched Gradient Descent, the coefficients of the target function is updated at the end of the all instance trained. For example: if i have 100 images to be trained, after 100th image got trained, cost is evaluated, and updated co-efficient.

2) For Stochastic Gradient descent, for this same 100 images, each image trained, the co-efficient are updated.

**Question:**

For Stochastic Gradient Descent,  it is claimed that the input images needs to be randomized in order to avoid being stuck. I could not imagine this problem. Could someone help?

Comment: Pure machine learning questions are not a good fit for Stack Overflow. Please consider searching on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) or another deep learning resource. In particular, this question looks like a cross-duplicate: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/49528/67965

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I read the link you provided, it doesn't seem to be addressing my question.

Answer (score 0):

Stochastic Gradient Descent do update by previous training data.

[image: SGD]

Therefore, we have to shuffle our training set prevent repeating same update.